# Convert a query from SQL to CodeIgniter

Tags: sql, codeigniter

This is the query I need to convert from SQL to CodeIgniter:

```
select *, count(username) as totalattempt from (select * from my_table order by created desc) as created2 group by `username` order by created desc
```

I've tried searching on Active Record CodeIgniter, but failed to get an answer.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried thus far?

Comment: Userguide http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codeigniter didn’t provided any option to use sub queries with active record class.

Try:

```
$this->db->select('*')->from('my_table')->order_by('created','DESC');
$subQuery =  $this->db->get_compiled_select();

/* Main Query */
$result = $this->db->select('created2.*, count(created2.username) as totalattempt')
     ->from('('.$subQuery.') as created2')
     ->group_by('created2.created','DESC')
     ->order_by('created2.username')
     ->get()
     ->result_array();
```

Thanks!